# Combobox Running Code/Query throwing "Recordset is not updateable"

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

When I click the Combobox, the dropdown list is populated, yet when I try to click on an option it says "Recordset is not updateable".. I have tried to read up on this error yet can't identify the issue behind this. The joins aren't complicated and it has worked before. The query source for the AwardsSubFrm is attached:[image]

[image: QBE]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of the query design indicates your record source is a `GROUP BY` query.  The recordset from any `GROUP BY` query is never updateable.  You can verify that point by opening the query in Datasheet View of the query designer and confirm Access won't let you change any of the values.

I don't know what the fix is for your situation, but you need something other than just a `GROUP BY` query.  Perhaps a subform whose record source contains the table rows you want to update, and link it to the main form so it displays those records which are related to the current main form row.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge! I'll try to see if I change some fields to "Expression" and see if that does anything. - Nope, it doesn't like that.

Comment: I did not actually need the "Totals" so I removed them and it worked! Thanks, HansUp!